# How to popup a page when a button is on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a new page to be opened in a popup when a button is pressed. Here is my code so far:

```
<td><input type="button" name="to" value="" style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none; onClick="myPopup()""> To:</td> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup() 
{
  window.open( "http://www.google.com/" )
}
</script>
```

When I pressed, it is fails. There is no popup when I pressed...I think the code I wrote is incorrect, but I am not sure. I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window with some specifications.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the `onclick` to the `style` property.  Looks like just mis-matched quotes.  Change this:

```
style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none; onClick="myPopup()""
```

to this:

```
style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none;" onClick="myPopup()"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, how do you get the popup to be on the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the Style tag and placed the its " after the onclick.

This should be working

```
<td><input type="button" name="to" value="" 

style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none;"

onClick="myPopup()"> To:</td> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup() 
{
  window.open( "http://www.google.com/" )
}
</script>
```